# Accessing related record data in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating database of ethernet switches that contains its name and IP address. Also I store list of active ports in that switch (those that are in UP state for the moment). In case of switch I use its IP address as primary key. Unfortunaly problem starts with list of ports. They can have duplicated names and numbers (because each switch can have port number one and also port named "uplink").

So my idea is to use ID of port in form "switch_ip:port_name" for example: "1.2.3.4:Gi0/1" or "4.5.6.7:20" in case port numbers are just numbers not names.

I wanto do it that way so `Session.merge()` works. So here is how I would see it:

```
class Switch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'switches'

    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    ip = Column(String(15), primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    ports = relationship("Port", order_by="Port.id", backref="switch")

    def __repr__(self):
            return "<Switch(name='%s', ip='%s')>" % (self.name, self.ip)

class Port(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ports'

    id = Column(String(160), primary_key=True)
    number = Column(Integer) 
    name = Column(String(32)) 
    description = Column(String(255))

    switch_ip = Column(String(15), ForeignKey('switches.ip'))
    macs = relationship("Mac", order_by="Mac.mac", backref="port")

    def __init__(self, id, name, description, number = None):
            self.name = name
            self.description = description
            self.number = number
            self.id = self.switch_ip + ":" + name

    def __repr__(self):
            return "<Port(switch='%s', name='%s', description='%s')>" % (self.switch_ip, self.name, self.description)
```

And thanks to that I could do something like this:

```
sw = Switch(name='some-switch',ip='1.2.3.4')
sw.ports = [ Port(name='Gi0/666', description='Uplink'), Port(name='Gi0/24', description='Apartament2') ]
```

Unfortunately in `Port.__init__` its attribute `switch_ip` is empty (`None`). But after storing it in database by `Session.add()` or `Session.merge()` it gets it value filled properly with 1.2.3.4. But it is too late. So how to get `switch_ip` value in `Port.__init__`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using context sensitive Column Insert Defaults (documented here - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html). First we create function returning proper name consisting of IP and name of port:

```
def portid(context):
    return context.current_parameters['switch_ip'] + ':' + context.current_parameters['name']
```

And then updated object definition:

```
class Port(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ports'

    id = Column(String(160), primary_key=True, default=portid)
    number = Column(Integer) 
    name = Column(String(32)) 
    description = Column(String(255))

    switch_ip = Column(String(15), ForeignKey('switches.ip'))
    macs = relationship("Mac", order_by="Mac.mac", backref="port")

    def __repr__(self):
            return "<Port(switch='%s', name='%s', description='%s')>" % (self.switch_ip, self.name, self.description)
```

And *voila*!